# Using conditionals to compare integers?

Tags: java

I'm writing a method that returns a String. The String is the name of the continent that the person using the App is more likely to be in.

Ie. There are two continents, A and B. If the person is somewhere in continent A the time to reach continent A should be less than continent B. In this case the String returned would be *"A"*.

These are the steps I have came up with to write the method:

1. calculate distances between 2 continents
2. Compare these distances using conditional statements
3. Find the smallest value and represent this with a name in the form of a string

I've already done #1. I'm very lost on as to how I can use conditional statement to compare the integer values.. The scope of the assignment is to use algorithm to write most of the method.. Can anyone tell me as to how I can start on the algorithm part? (there's also a total of 7 locations I have to take into account)

This is the code I have so far:

```
public String whichContinent(ILocationService locator) {
    int na = locator.timeToNorthAmerica();
    int sa = locator.timeToSouthAmerica();
    int e = locator.timeToEurope();
    int a = locator.timeToAsia();
    int af = locator.timeToAfrica();
    int au = locator.timeToAustralia();
    int an = locator.timeToAntarctica();
    return "a string";
}
```

Comment: Show us how far you've got with the code...

Comment: That's the code I have so far

Comment: Is there a way that I can say that if (na < sa, e, a, af, au, an) return "North America".... in correct java syntax?

Comment: As one _cannot_ make one large expression, keep a minimum time and its continent's name. Then for all values compare minimum time an value - per value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TreeMap` to store and sort by distance with distance as key. After you have inserted all the records, just get the first entry in the map and return it's value. First entry is the place with nearest distance.

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> distances = new TreeMap<>();
distances.put(na, "NorthAmerica");
...

return distances.firstEntry().getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
String continentName = null;
for (Continent continent : continents) {
    if (continent.getDistanceFromLocation(locator) < distance) {
        continentNAme = continent.getName():
    }
{
return continentName;
```